# C++ ::: Cannot call error, as instructed to in Stroustrup's book

Tags: c++, function, identifier

I have decided to take it upon myself to learn C++, I already have some experience with Java.

In Bjarne Stroustrup's Book he says:

> Prompt the user to enter the age of the recipient and assign it to an
>   **int** variable **age**. Have your program write "*I hear you just had a
>   birthday and You are '**age**' years old.*" If **age** is 0 or less or 110 or
>   more, ***call error("you're kidding! ")***.

A few pages prior to that, he uses the error function as follows:

> double d1 = 2.3;
>
> double d2 = d1 + 2;
>
> if (d1 < 0)
>
> error( "d1 is negative");

When I try to run my program (Exercise from Bjarnes book), I get " **Use of undeclared Identifier 'error'** ".

I have tried to research my issue, which has yielded me a solution everytime until now, to no avail.

In case it is needed, here is the content of my Main.cpp:

> ```
> #include <iostream> 
> using namespace std;
>
> int main() {
>
>     cout << "Please enter the recipients name: " << endl;
>     string rname;
>     getline(cin, rname);
>
>     cout << "Ok, thank you. What is your mutual friends name: " <<endl;
>     string fname;
>     getline (cin, fname);
>
>     cout << "Ok, now what gender is you friends? 'm' for male, and 'f' for female: ";
>     char fsex;
>     cin >> fsex;
>
>     cout << "Fantastic, now how old is the recipient? " << endl;
>     int age;
>     cin >> age;
>     if(age >= 0 && age <= 110){
>         cout << "Thank you " << endl;
>     }
>     if(age <= 0 && age >= 110){
>         error("You're Kidding!");
>     }
>
>
>
>     return 0; }
> ```

Comment: You probably missed to declare and define a function `error()` as explained in a previous section or chapter.

Comment: No I searched, and did a search for keyword "error", it was not explained in the previous section.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include header

```
std_lib_facilities.h
```

See [the header definition](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h)

Comment: Thank you Vlad,

I'm using QT Creator on Mac, and it doesn't have this library!

I just tried to import and include the std_lib_facilities.h file, but I get 'a lot' of undefined errors! Any ideas?

Comment: @Haddaraboy You simply should copy iusing the refernce I gave or type it yourself.

Comment: @Haddaraboy The other way is to type only the function as it is defined in the hader.

Comment: Ok goona get on it, Thank Vlad! +rep :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the error `Use of undeclared Identifier 'error'` means that you're trying to call a function called `error`, but the compiler has no idea where to find that function.

You need to declare and define that function somewhere, for example like this :

```
void error(char* str) {
    puts(str);
}
```

Just like in Java, you can't use a function if it doesn't exist anywhere.